# iOS - scrolling over a drawing bigger than screen

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, draw

I'm trying to do something like calendar's day view. On android I created a canvas (bigger than the screen) and put it on a scrollview. Everything was great. After the draw, I was able to scroll over my canvas.

But at iOS, when I draw on the UIScrollView, I cannot do any scroll gestures on my screen. Can anyone help me?

```
 for (int i = 1; i <18; i++){

    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, i*80, 240, 1)];
    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:lineView];

    int n = i+7;
    NSString *str = nil;
    if(n<10){
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d:00", n];
    }
    else{str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:00", n];}

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
    NSMutableAttributedString *s2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSPlainTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    [s2 addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} range:NSMakeRange(0, s2.length)];

    UILabel *hour = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*80-4, 240, 10)];
    hour.attributedText = s2;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:hour];
```

Comment: Did you set your scrollView's contentSize correctly?

Comment: Yip.. I made it 568; which is full screen, and tried 900 and 1800 :D  nothing changed...

Comment: Show your code where you create the scrollview.

Comment: No need guys.. Thank you @Marco, I thought everything about the scrollView's height.. I thought it can resize itself... I assumed contentSize is the height but looked now and everything is OK. Thank you again guys... I couldn't still get used to iOS, wasted your time. Sorry :/